# How to read the text files in gzip format without unzipping it write that line to excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Problem Statement :**
I have a directory with gzip files , and each gzip file contains a text file.
I have written a code in such a way that it unzips all the gzip files and then used to read each unzipped text file and then combined  that output to one text file, then applied a condition , if that condition meets then it writes to excel.
       The above process is bit tedious and lengthy.
Can anyone please help me out in writing the code where the data is read directly from the txt file which is gzipped and write it contents to excel.

Comment: you have to unzip them to read the contents, but im pretty sure you could unzip them in memory

Comment: What about using [gzcat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813451/what-does-the-gzcat-and-zcat-command-do) ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use pandas using first [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = read_csv('yourfile.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

then apply your conditions on `df` and write back the dataframe to excel using [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel(file.xls)
```